# Here API - Implement nearby places feature

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocation, maps, here-api

I am looking for a way to implement the nearby places functionality BUT with my own set of places using HERE API.

I expect there should be a function where I could insert my own places on the map and after
that search the nearby places of a specific place within a radius.

I cannot find anything related to this kind of problem.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Can you have a function to get the route duration from origin to all your places and then sort your places based on the route duration (or how close they are)?

You can look into the routing API: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.8.0/dev_guide/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out the [Custom Locations API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/custom-location/dev_guide/topics/what-is.html). This API allows you to upload and then search for custom location information. This includes a proximity search.

Comment: Yepp that's what I was looking for. Thank you so much!